# Video player with URL/URI for android

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

Hi Everybody,
             I am  new to android. I want to make custom video player with capability to play videos from YouTube. My question is, i want to set video URI or URL for video player. How can i achieve the goal.
I have searched over internet but found no any help. So please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: I think question was not such bad. I have made enough research effort to make my custom video player and found no related help or stuff then why you guys are downgrading me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fenster](https://github.com/malmstein/fenster) Library on Github. This library can fulfill your requirements.

**OR**

Take a look at the dev guide for more info [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer%28%29).